# query powershell to pull users from a list and return all of their groups to a file

Tags: powershell, csv, group

I have a list of 800+ users that I would like to get a list of each user's AD groups and then output the user's name(samAccountName in my file) and their groups to a file.
I have tried the following code, but it does not put the Account name, and is not parsing all of the entries in the file - I have 9 entries, I get a text file with 5 groupings of groups.
The code I am using:

```
$users = Get-Content C:\scripts\vendors.txt

ForEach ($User in $users) {
  Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | select $user.samaccountname |Select Name | Sort Name | ft @{L='Current Groups';E={$PSItem.Name}} -AutoSize | Out-File  -append c:\scripts\vendorlog.txt 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's possible.

Comment: I'm assuming you're looking for export to have 2 columns, 1 for the user's `samAccountName` and the other column for group name they're a member of?

Comment: Yes, 2 columns - samAccountName and Groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know how to get a user's membership via [`Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adprincipalgroupmembership?view=windowsserver2022-ps), seems like you only need help with enumerating each group and then merging that output with the user being processed, for that you can use [`PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.2) to instantiate and output new objects, then that output can be captured and exported to CSV with [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.2).

```bash
Get-Content C:\scripts\vendors.txt | ForEach-Object {
    try {
        foreach($group in Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                UserName = $_
                MemberOf = $group.Name
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning $_
    }
} | Export-Csv path/to/myExport.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you! How to I make it so that each user and all of their groups just takes up one row and the groups are up and down, rather than in a string?

Comment: @mrcgray are you sure you want something like that? You wouldn't be able to (in Excel) filter that output as you want it

Comment: Good point.  Ok, where and how would I add some display on the screen  to tell the person running the script what record it's working on? Or something other than just the blinking cursor.

Comment: @mrcgray have a look at [`Write-Progress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress?view=powershell-7.2) though this is not part of the initial question. If my answer solved your query please consider accepting it